# Weird route malfunction, mix between devise and own controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, link-to

I've got a real weird route behavior. I spotted the line which, i think, cause the error.
Here is the line (in application.html.erb) in question :

```
<%= link_to "Official Top", :controller => "tops", :action => "show", :id => 10 %>
```

The problem happens when i want to sign in with devise, when i go to this link :

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in 
using <%= link_to "sign in", new_user_session_path %>
```

Without the line everything is fine, but when the line is present i've got this error :

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/tops", :action=>"show", :id=>10}
```

What is the connection with this line oO Why it mix devise and tops ? How can this line trouble the route for devise ? Really weird ... besides all my routes seems fine

```
new_user_session GET   /users/sign_in(.:format)   devise/sessions#new
top GET                /tops/:id(.:format)        tops#show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
<%= link_to "Official Top", :controller => "/tops", :action => "show", :id => 10 %>
```

I think adding the "/" will solve your problem, as it is now searching for the Tops controller within the Devise directory ... with the "/", it will search in the "home controllers" directory instead

Comment: Yep it solved it ! thanks ! But is it normal ? I've never seen / in thoses type of links :/ As it is, it might happen in other situations :( And we don't always know where we are so should I use / everytime ?

Comment: Indeed, it's strange behaviour, I don't think this is "normal", but I only encountered this behaviour with Devise ... I spent 3 hours a few months ago to discover I needed to add a "/" so I am happy that I could help you with this :-)... By the way, don't hesitate to mark the answer as "Accepted" if you are happy with the answer, and you can even vote it up ;-) ...

Comment: (yep sorry i had to wait 15min to accept the answer) Yeah that's what I think too it's a strange behaviour ... Hope it will not interfere with anything else in future development :/
If someone has an explanation, I would be glad to understand it.