# devise creates malfunction in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I already had an issue with devise that i posted here : [Weird route malfunction, mix between devise and own controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452866/weird-route-malfunction-mix-between-devise-and-own-controller)
I was hoping it was just a one time issue but devise is driving me crazy !

If I do this everything is ok

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.ideas.include?(@idea) %>
    <%= button_to 'Remove from Favorites', user_idea_subscription(@idea.id), method:    :delete%>
  <% else %>
    <%= button_to 'Add to Favorites', user_idea_subscriptions_path(current_user, :idea_id => @idea) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But if I do this :

```
<% if user_signed_in? and current_user.ideas.include?(@idea) %>
  <%= button_to 'Remove from Favorites', user_idea_subscription(@idea.id), method:    :delete%>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'Add to Favorites', user_idea_subscriptions_path(current_user, :idea_id => @idea) %>
<% end %>
```

Then I've got this error :

```
No route matches {:controller=>"idea_subscriptions", :idea_id=>#<Idea id: 12, name: "Chute libre", description: "50sec a 50m/s", created_at: "2012-07-12 10:02:30", updated_at: "2012-07-12 10:02:30">}
```

Everything should be ok but why I'm getting that error ? (beside there is no other information on the error)
Thanks for your help and my sanity !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is normal behaviour because in second case you are trying to call

```
user_idea_subscriptions_path(current_user, :idea_id => @idea)
```

then user is not signed in, so `current_user` is nil

Comment: Oh ok thx ! I was doing this because even if the user is not signed in I wanted to let him see the add favorites button but within the controller i will set a flash notice "sign up to add idea as favorite" and redirect to @idea. How can I do that then ?

Comment: You can't use this path helper without user_id, so u have to use another path for unauthorized users or just use some javascript with "#not_authorized" url.